# Sql error in website

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query with the following `SELECT` statement:

`(ascii(substring((SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name =\'admin-modules\' LIMIT 1,1),1,1))) > 0-- -`

But this gives me the following error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'admin-modules\' limit 1,1),1,1))) > 0-- -' at line 1`

Can someone help me figure out why I'm getting the error?

Comment: Your error message tells you what the problem is.

Comment: Also note that `LIMIT 1,1` selects the second row in your query, not the first (which is what I assume you were after). `LIMIT` with 2 arguments is `LIMIT OFFSET, COUNT`. Offset should be 0 for the first row. It should be `LIMIT 0,1` for only the first row. Or `SELECT TOP 1` if you aren't dealing with a lot of rows in your query.

Comment: EDIT: Oops. MySQL doesn't do `TOP`. Ignore that part. :-/

Answer (score 0):

This is far from SQL syntax. The best I can make from this, is that you try to do this command:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name =\'admin-modules\' 
LIMIT 1
```

If you save this result as `result` maybe you could later do

```
ascii(substring(result, 1),1)
```

But I still wouldn't have a clue what `> 0-- -` is doing here. I guess nobody knows

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this is "far from SQL syntax". You even suggest changing the SQL syntax as part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape `'` with a backslash. The sql query should be:

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'admin-modules' limit 1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

See my notes above. The syntax error was in nesting the initial select instead of trying to do your `ascii(substring())` on the selected column before the `FROM/WHERE`.

**Setup:**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE foo (column_name varchar(10), table_name varchar(10));
>
> INSERT INTO foo (column_name, table_name)
> SELECT 'a','table1'  UNION ALL
> SELECT 'b','table1'  UNION ALL
> SELECT 'col1','table2'  UNION ALL
> SELECT 'c3','table1'  
> ;
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> SELECT 
>       substring(column_name,1,1) AS subCN
>     , ascii(substring(column_name,1,1)) AS asciiSubCN
>     , ascii(substring(column_name,1,1)) > 0 AS isASCII
> FROM foo 
> WHERE table_name='table1' 
> LIMIT 0,1  -- This can be LIMIT 1 for just 1st row.
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> subCN | asciiSubCN | isASCII
> :---- | ---------: | -------:
> a     |         97 |        1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=014d94e5797eda3935530a9bcb484f86)*

You have to put your `SELECT`ed columns in the right positions of the query. So this would change your `SELECT` above to

`SELECT ascii(substring(column_name,1,1)) > 0 AS isASCII FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'admin-modules' LIMIT 1)`

The `-- -` (and anything after it in the line) will be ignored since `--` is a SQL single-line comment indicator.